# Google Places for iOS SDK v3.2.0 throwing errors

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-places, google-places-autocomplete

After updating to the latest version (3.2.0) from 2.7.0, the Google places SDK for iOS is throwing an error when I'm calling the new method findAutocompletePredictions:

The method GMSClient.provideAPIKey returns true but the places client is not able to make any requests. What is interesting is that with the same API key, everything works with version 2.7.0.

The error message is: 
Operation failed due to an invalid (malformed or missing) API key.

Comment: Do you have the Places API enabled on your project? Is your API key correctly restricted? Have you enabled billing? Have you [fully migrated](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/client-migration) to the new Places SDK for IOS? Please double check these and let us know.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Have you figured it out ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable the Places API - https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/places-backend.googleapis.com
2. Update the code of your application as indicated here - https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/client-migration.